# Como contornar a má renderização de um tipo de letra no Internet Explorer?

Tags: css, html

Estou utilizando um font-kit gerado no [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) e estou obtendo resultados diferentes em ambiente Mac OS X e Windows.

Haveria alguma forma de contornar a má ou diferente renderização da fonte de Internet Explorer?

**No Mac OS X:**

[image: No Mac OS X]

**No Windows 7:**

[image: No Windows 7]

```css
@font-face {
    font-family:'Exo';
    src: url('/sys/resources/font-kits/exo/exo-regular.eot');
    src: url('/sys/resources/font-kits/exo/exo-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/sys/resources/font-kits/exo/exo-regular.svg#ArchitectsDaughterRegular') format('svg'),
         url('/sys/resources/font-kits/exo/exo-regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/sys/resources/font-kits/exo/exo-regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Qual o formato da fonte? Como está configurada a suavização de fontes no windows?

Comment: @font-face {
    font-family: 'Exo';
    src: url('/sys/resources/font-kits/exo/exo-regular.eot');
    src: url('/sys/resources/font-kits/exo/exo-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/sys/resources/font-kits/exo/exo-regular.svg#ArchitectsDaughterRegular') format('svg'),
         url('/sys/resources/font-kits/exo/exo-regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/sys/resources/font-kits/exo/exo-regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

Comment: clear-type no windows

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Existem diversos fatores para a apresentação diferenciada das fontes nos diversos sistemas, principalmente no que se refere à *engine* utilizado pelo sistema operacional e ao algoritmo de *anti-aliasing* e, no caso do Windows, ao *ClearType*.

Por outro lado, você está usando um formato de inclusão de `@font-face`, o que deveria minimizar as diferenças já que existem vários formatos específicos para cada tipos de browser e sistema operacional.

Se estivesse no seu lugar, alternaria os diversos tipos de fonte, inibindo os demais e faria um teste para ver se dá alguma diferença, afinal o IE pode não estar lendo a URL que você espera e que tenha melhor compatibilidade no ambiente Windows.

Entretanto, baseado [neste artigo](http://annystudio.com/misc/anti-aliased-fonts-hurt/) e [neste tópico](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/265/font-face-loaded-on-windows-look-really-bad-which-fonts-are-you-using-that-rend) eu diria que a "falha" no desenho de algumas letras é oriunda de particularidades da fonte que, ao serem processadas no algoritmo de *ClearType*, acabam visualmente "danificadas".

Se eu estiver correto, a fonte que você utilizou é [esta](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/exo). Eu fiz o download do OTF original e abri o arquivo no windows XP. *Aparentemente* ela tem características que podem causar problemas de renderização, como alguns pixels isolados nos cantos das letras.

Comment: Sim 90% da falha está na fonte, já deu para ver no font studio. Há forma de contornar a má renderização, que é subir ou descer o corpo de letra, ou usando um bold. Aparentemente o aspecto melhora.

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 5):

Somente utilizando uma **imagem** para ter o mesmo resultado em qualquer browser e sistema operacional.

A maneira como o texto é renderizado no browser depende de diversos fatores como sistema operacional, calibração e parâmetros da renderização.

Não podemos esperar que a renderização da fonte seja a mesma em qualquer ambiente.

Comment: Não posso usar imagens... este website é traduzido para umas 30 línguas diferentes, logo aquelas strings são variáveis. Além de que são dinâmicas, o cliente pode edita-las.

Comment: Apenas uma ideia, caso alguém ainda ache mais conveniente usar imagem e ainda assim o texto ser gerado dinamicamente, pode-se utilizar `Perl` e `Gimp` para produzir o resultado. [Ver o item 7 deste tutorial](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Perl/).

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver problemas como o seu eu tenho um [GIST (sobre Font-Face)](https://gist.github.com/rickbenetti/5a155b503d724b52d9d2) no github que aplica um conjunto de regras no body e 2 tipos de importação de fonte sendo que hoje só utilizo o mais novo.

**Conteúdo do GIST:**

```css
/**
 * Adicionar ao CSS após o CSS Reset
 *
 * Sites para Converter Fonts em WebFonts
 *   http://convertfonts.com/
 *   http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator
 *   http://fontface.codeandmore.com/
 **/

 * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {     
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -ms-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
  -ms-text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px transparent;
  -moz-text-stroke: 1px transparent;
  -ms-text-stroke: 1px transparent;
  text-stroke: 1px transparent;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
```

**E o tipo de importação:**

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'font_desejada';
  src: url('fonts/font_desejada.eot');
  src: url('fonts/font_desejada.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('fonts/font_desejada.svg#FontDesejada') format('svg'),
       url('fonts/font_desejada.woff') format('woff');   
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```